# How to displays list of hyperlinks when cursor moves over an element, when we click on a hyperlink it should open a new page

Tags: html, css

let's say "Games" is a text, when the user moves the cursor over "Games", the hyperlinks are displayed (Football, Basketball)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sports</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <p> Games</p>
</nav>
<div>
    <a href="">Football</a>
    <a href="">Basketball</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this using HTML and CSS only.

Is it possible ?

Comment: <a href="#">GAMES</a>

Comment: Hover effects can be done using `:hover` in `css`. For mode detailed answer you need to post some code, otherwise, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

with hover effect you can display a text
you have to add the folowing code here.

```
enter code  <nav class = "myDIV">
<p> Games</p>
</nav>
<div class="hide">
<a href="">Football</a>
<a href="">Basketball</a>
</div>
```

css part:

```
 .hide {
  display: none;
}

.myDIV:hover + .hide {
display: block;
color: red;
}
```

to open a link in a new page you have to use target=blank inside a tag

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

## Using only the adjacent sibling combinator

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

This one will be compatible with almost any browser but it's using a trick that actually breaks the requirement.. we are observing the element `nav` for `:hover` and not strictly its paragraph first child.

```css
nav+div {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sports</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <p>Games</p>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <a href="">Football</a>
    <a href="">Basketball</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Using the :has() pseudo class

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

This one will work only with Chrome >=105 (so far) but surely fits better the expectations because it will trigger the visibility of the anchors only when the paragraph first child of the `nav` element will be on `:hover`

```css
nav>p:first-child {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav+div {
  display: none;
}

nav:has(> p:first-child:hover)+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sports</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <p>Games</p>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <a href="">Football</a>
    <a href="">Basketball</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```